# I need help on the meaning and translation of 絶賛不登校

Tags: translation, meaning, words, expressions

I came across this word in a manga that I'm translating. I understand that it has something to do with not attending school, but I can't for the life of me figure out what "絶賛" means when placed in front of 不登校. I haven't found any dictionary entries for it either.